# Checking for identical columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose you have a data frame called data with two identical columns:

```
A B
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

How can I check if these two columns are identical and return **one** logical value to indicate it? A very basic pseudocode is:

```
if(data$A == data$B)
{
   print("Column A and B are identical")
}
```

I have been messing around with this for a bit and haven't found a way to do it that doesn't seem unnecessarily convoluted. Thanks.

Comment: Are your columns just integers?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the columns are character values.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use `identical`

```
identical(DT[['A']],DT[['B']])
```

Answer (score 30):

You could use [`all()`](http://rfunction.com/archives/1263):

```
> data <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4), B=c(1,2,3,4))
> all(data$A == data$B)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest yet still effective answer to this question.

Comment: Works well if you do not have NAs in your data. identical was a better solution for my case.

Answer (score 5):

This might be overkill for your problem, but you may also want to look into `compare()` from the "compare" package. Consider the following examples:

```
> data <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4), B = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
> compare(data[1], data[2]) ## Should be false
FALSE [TRUE]
> compare(data[1], data[2], ignoreNames = TRUE) # Allow different names
TRUE
  dropped names
> data <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4), B = as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 4)))
> str(data) ## "B" is now a factor, so use `coerce` to test for equality
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: num  1 2 3 4
 $ B: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4
> compare(data[1], data[2], ignoreNames = TRUE, coerce = TRUE)
TRUE
  [A] coerced from <factor> to <numeric>
  dropped names
```

There is a general logical argument, `allowAll`, that can be set to `TRUE` to allow the `compare` function to try different transformations to test for equality.

Comment: Overkill, maybe. But nice handy function!

Answer (score 0):

A general method and valid to test all the columns at once is to check for duplicates in a transposed data frame:

```r
DF <- data.frame(a=1:4,b=6:7,c=8:9,d=1:4,e=8:9)
duplicated(t(DF)) 

# Trues are duplicated 
# Falses are first originals

    a     b     c     d     e 
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 


duplicated(t(DF),fromLast=T)

# Falses are the last originals

    a     b     c     d     e 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Interesting, but it only tells you the second duplicate column, but won't tell you which was the first one. ```duplicated(t(DF %>% select(my_column, my_other_column, my_duplicate)))
my_column   my_other_column   my_duplicate 
        FALSE    FALSE    TRUE ``` (Sorry about formatting)

Comment: If you want to know which are the first one originals, you can simply negate the expression: `!duplicated(t(DF))`

Comment: Not quite - the negated expression includes the non-duplicated column. Using `fromLast` is closer to what I was thinking I'd want. Then you can combine them to get both duplicates `duplicated(t(DF)) | duplicated(t(DF),fromLast=T)`